# Beamer: Center only a part of text

Tags: beamer

I want to put some left-bottom-aligned text on a beamer title page, where *the title and name are perfectly centered*. How do I do this? As soon as I put something under the centered text, it will de-center (raise) it, as the centering applies to everything on the slide no matter what. The MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\centering
\Huge{The Title as Such}\\
\Large{The Author}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip
\normalsize{some text}
\end{minipage}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a `minipage`, you can use TeX's primitive `\vskip0pt plus 1filll` which will insert a vertical skip of at least `0pt` but is infinitely stretchable to the available space, to the bottom of the slide in our case. The vertically centered text will be inserted between two `\newvfill`s as follows.

```
\documentclass{beamer}     
\begin{document}    

\newcommand{\newvfill}{\vskip0pt plus 1filll}       
\begin{frame}    
\newvfill

\begin{center}
\Huge{The Title as Such}\par
\Large{The Author}
\end{center}

\newvfill
some text
\bigskip
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: This is useful (+1) but adding and removing `\bigskip`s will move the centered text around, so `some text` cannot appear further up w/ the title centered. I'll accept a solution where the position of `some text` may vary while the title remains centered

Comment: OK, I found a way to do this (and added it to your answer)